# Debugging "[Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.]" in Node

Tags: node.js

My node app has this line appearing sporadically in its output:

[Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.]

However, there is no callstack or any other information.  What's the appropriate way to debug this type of error?

Comment: post your code, when you want us to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I was silly enough to be using this code that I found somewhere:

> process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
>     console.log(err);
>   });

It ended up hiding the interesting data, namely the callstack.

Comment: Worth noting that Node's new domains feature might be useful for catching errors in third party code.  http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html